# How can I identity if a view has been truncated?

Tags: android, android-view

I have the following layout. In the example below, you will notice that `Y` was not able to be laid out to its full width, and it was cut-off (truncated) due to the lack of vertical space.

[image]

I would like to be able to programmatically identify when this happens (as a `Boolean`. How can I achieve this?

Note: the answer to this question will enable a workaround for this problem [How can I use ConstraintLayout to have the first View shrink to fit remaining space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278029/how-can-i-use-constraintlayout-to-have-the-first-view-shrink-to-fit-remaining-sp/58313591?noredirect=1#comment103011808_58313591)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fbe9e7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="X"
        android:textSize="96sp">

    </TextView>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_Y"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f3e5f5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Y"
    android:textSize="96sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView" 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_topTopOf="@+barrier_bottom"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="bottom"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="text_Z,spacer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spacer
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_constraintTop_topBottomOf="@+id/text_Y"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_Z"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e1f5fe"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Z"
    android:textSize="96sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post some xml?

Comment: @adneal check out the XML in the post I linked